# How to preserve variadic type order for conditionally inferred conditional types?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have the following type definition:

```js
type Inner<Type> = Type extends Wrapper<infer U>[] ? U[] : never;
```

and a function with this sort of signature:

```js
function myFunc<From extends Wrapper[], To>(
    values: From,
    transform: (v: Inner<From>) => To
)
```

When I pass a callback as the `transform` argument, the argument list for that callback is inferred as an array of union types rather than preserving the order.

So, if `values` is `[Wrapper<number>, Wrapper<string>]`, then the arguments inferred for `transform` are `(number|string)[]` (with the order gone) when what I wanted was `[number, string]`.

Is there any way to preserve the order in this case?

*Edit
For the purposes here, you can assume that `Wrapper` is something like `type Wrapper<T> = {x:T}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question, I'm going to assume that `Wrapper<T>` has a structural dependence on `T`, which apparently [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to something like unrestrictive like `any`:

```
type Wrapper<T = any> = { x: T };
```

---

You should make `Inner` a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), since these will automatically [map arrays to arrays and tuples to tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays):

```
type Inner<T extends Wrapper[]> =
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Wrapper<infer U> ? U : never };
```

Then your `myFunc()` should work more or less as-is:

```
declare function myFunc<W extends Wrapper[], T>(
    values: [...W],
    transform: (v: Inner<W>) => T
): void;
```

I changed the type of `values` to `[...W]`, a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) which gives the compiler a hint that you'd like it to infer `values` as a tuple if possible (otherwise an array literal you mean to be a `[Wrapper<number>, Wrapper<string>]` would instead be interpreted as `Array<Wrapper<number> | Wrapper<string>>` and any benefit from the mapped type would be lost.

---

Let's test it, with what I hope is what you were talking about in the question:

```
declare const wn: Wrapper<number>;
declare const ws: Wrapper<string>;

myFunc([wn, ws], v => v[1].length < v[0])
// (parameter) v: [number, string]
// function myFunc<[Wrapper<number>, Wrapper<string>], boolean>
```

Looks good.  IntelliSense shows that `values` is interpreted as being of type `[Wrapper<number>, Wrapper<string>]`, and therefore `v` is inferred to be `[number, string]`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=35&pln=11&pc=35#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzJOAeAKlAvFBA7EAPmygG8oAPALikwF8BuAKCdEigEk88I1MIKwCHgAmAZ1iJkvANoBdYliZQVZKDIDSUAJZ4oAawggA9gDNacmuk1yoAoaInwkKVLtO8oAVWIB+b1A0PABunowsIhAAxgA2CHDQpgCueFHA2sZ6ALYgAGIpUagwdoLC4pIusnIANLSEABTKqsEIMUkQYjQyAHS9MDVNKsCIeGKmxnBZNPXBNFw8aDCEAJTYxOhMyzTBxtoizEyRsfHQUZliwFAA7ng0ztJoeElZAEa8hMxHcQlQZ6OXV06FQeqAucF0AHMPiwcvlUvUZDdaoCalBgms0TIAIxyboxYQQ4AACygqExAAY5MsmAB6GlQZKpdKZKCwgqoGT3VxPV7vWpc3ig4aQwiol7GYz4-CEIA)

Comment: I'm relieved I don't need to make a bunch of overload signatures, phew! Thanks again!